# Nested many-to-many relationships in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

Each user can follow many categories (many to many),
Each category has many posts (one to many),

I want to get all posts followed by the user and sort them by date.

Is there any way to do that with Eloquent?

Comment: Could you provide some of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a different way, but how I'd probably do it is with two queries:

```
// Get the IDs of the categories
$categoryIds = $user->categories()->pluck('id');

// Pull the posts with those category IDs
$posts = Post::whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds)->get();
```